# dynamic sampled query in oracle db trace

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, trace, cost-based-optimizer

i've got a huge Oracle Trace file. The application, wich produced this file, runned 1 hour and 15 minutes.
In this Tracefile i found 4 Selects with together a little bit over a hour runtime. 
The problem is these selects are sampled by the Optimizer.

```
SELECT /* OPT_DYN_SAMP */ /*+ ALL_ROWS IGNORE_WHERE_CLAUSE 
  NO_PARALLEL(SAMPLESUB) opt_param('parallel_execution_enabled', 'false') 
  NO_PARALLEL_INDEX(SAMPLESUB) NO_SQL_TUNE */ NVL(SUM(C1),:"SYS_B_00"), 
  NVL(SUM(C2),:"SYS_B_01") 
FROM
 (SELECT /*+ IGNORE_WHERE_CLAUSE NO_PARALLEL("LST_G") FULL("LST_G") 
  NO_PARALLEL_INDEX("LST_G") */ :"SYS_B_02" AS C1, CASE WHEN 
  "LST_G"."SENDUNG_TIX"=:"SYS_B_03" AND "LST_G"."LST_K"=:"SYS_B_04" AND 
  "LST_G"."LST_ART"=:"SYS_B_05" AND "LST_G"."FAK_TIX"=(-:"SYS_B_06") THEN 
  :"SYS_B_07" ELSE :"SYS_B_08" END AS C2 FROM "TMS1033"."LST_G" SAMPLE BLOCK 
  (:"SYS_B_09" , :"SYS_B_10") SEED (:"SYS_B_11") "LST_G") SAMPLESUB


call     count       cpu    elapsed       disk      query    current        rows
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
Parse    56076      3.93       4.21          0          0          0           0
Execute  56076      1.98       1.80          0          0          0           0
Fetch    56076   1127.54    1122.77        222   46487004          0       56076
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
total   168228   1133.45    1128.79        222   46487004          0       56076
```

This is one of the four, they look nearly the same. I think i found the original Statements and these are executed from a Uniface-Service. I have no idea how Uniface works, i am only the db guy. 
The problem is that i have no Idea why the Optimizer rebuild this statement. The original one don't use the `dynamic_sample` hint. Also i found these, i think so, original Statments additionally in the trace file .

```
select count(*) 
from
 lst_g where sendung_tix = 10330805990396 and lst_k = 'E' and lst_art = 'G' 
  and fak_tix = -4
```

Thats why i am not sure what these sampled Statements are. Any idea?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic sampling is turned on for that query.  Either

1. The query uses the `/*+ DYNAMIC_SAMPLING */` hint
2. The code issues an `alter session set optimizer_dynamic_sampling=` command
3. optimizer_dynamic_sampling is set in the database spfile.

For example

```
alter session set OPTIMIZER_DYNAMIC_SAMPLING = 2;
```

Then issue a query against a big table with a very selective (but not exact) condition that can use an index.

```
select * from mtl_system_items /* biiig table */ 
where organization_id = 92 
and segment1 LIKE 'DY_'  /* very selective condition with index */
```

Run it and you get data back quickly.  But then,

```
alter session set OPTIMIZER_DYNAMIC_SAMPLING = 10;
```

and re-run the same `SELECT` and it's out to lunch, sampling every block in the table.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score -1):

I believe these are queries used by Statistics Gathering jobs for updating statistics on database objects. Please check if any stats gathering / update jobs were running at the time when the trace file got generated.

In your case, from the SQL posted it seems statistics was being gathered on "TMS1033"."LST_G". The same will be the case with the other 3 SQLs you found out.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, I hate to down vote, but this isn't right.  These queries are not from DBMS_STATS.  They're from the optimizer performing dynamic sampling.  You can tell by (A) the OPT_DYN_SAMP comment in the query and (B) by the fact that the query has a WHERE clause on specific columns in the table.  DBMS_STATS would sample from all the rows (no where clause, just a sample size).